# Get the latest posts/data from firebase with limit 10 records in android and populate in Listview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

In my application I want to get the latest records from firebase with pagination of 10. Also i want to show them im listview when the limit reaches 10 , then it should again call the next 10 records and so on.
Can anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Add some of your code. What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort firebase records you can do one workaround. Add one extra field while updating or adding records. That field would be nothing but timestamp and then simple use order by timestamps. hope this helps.

```
item.timestamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild('metrics/timestamps');
```